# Magento 2 Rest Api V1/products missing extension attributes

Tags: rest, product, catalog, magento-2.0

I am calling the Rest API V1/products to get the product list from Magento 2 store

Request:

```
 http://{myMagentohost}/Magento/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[currentPage]=1&searchCriteria[pageSize]=1
```

Response:

```
 {"items": [ { "id": 1,"sku": "24-MB01","name": "Joust Duffle Bag","attribute_set_id": 15,"price": 34,"status": 1,"visibility": 4,"type_id": "simple","created_at": "2017-06-13 09:36:11","updated_at": "2017-06-13 09:36:11","product_links": [{"sku": "24-MB01", "link_type": "upsell","linked_product_sku": "24-MB03","linked_product_type": "simple","position": null,"extension_attributes": []},{"sku": "24-B01","link_type": "upsell","linked_product_sku": "24-WB04","linked_product_type": "simple","position": null,"extension_attributes": []}],"options": [],"tier_prices": [],"custom_attributes": [{"attribute_code": "description","value": "<p>The sporty Joust Duffle Bag can't be beat - ot in the gym, not on the luggage carousel, not anywhere. Big enough to haul a basketball or soccer ball and some sneakers with plenty of room to spare, it's ideal for athletes with places to go.<p>\n<ul>\n<li>Dual top handles.</li>\n<li>Adjustable shoulder strap.</li>\n<li>Full-length zipper.</li>\n<li>L 29\" x W 13\" x H 11\".</li>\n</ul>"},{"attribute_code": "image","value": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"},{"attribute_code": "small_image","value": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"},{"attribute_code": "thumbnail","value": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"},{"attribute_code": "url_key","value": "joust-duffle-bag"}]}],"search_criteria": {"filter_groups": [],"page_size": 1,"current_page": 1},"total_count": 2046}
```

Now according to the Magento 2 Rest API [swagger](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/) documentation, 
catalogProductRepositoryV1, GET /V1/products in response it shows the extension_attributes but when I actually call this api from postman extension_attributes is missing.

I  search for it but no appropriate solution is available.

Can anyone help in this matter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We are using M2Ent Cloud Edt and we have an open ticket with Magento support who confirm this is a problem with the REST API.

To circumvent, we initially looped through all products via V1/products using pagination (Fastly as a 60s timeout otherwise), and then called V1/products/{sku} to get all the details (which correctly includes the extension_attributes node.

They have not given us an ETA on a fix.

Comment: We also had to make a separate request per product to get the custom attribute data. Annoying...